# Reference to Current Excel file/Sheet

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, instance

I made a wizard button on a Access form where you can transfer the data of a Query to a new excel file and then the new file will automatically open. 
Is there a way to make a reference to this new file or Sheet, because i want to put something in this new file.

Answer (score 1):

This will get an open instance of Excel if it exists or create one if there isn't one.

```
Public Function GetExcelApp() As Excel.Application
' Returns open excel instance.
'   If it doesn't exist, creates one to return
On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Const PROC_NAME As String = "GetExcelApp"
Const ERR_APP_NOTRUNNING As Long = 429

    Set GetExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

CleanExit:
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number = ERR_APP_NOTRUNNING Then
        Set GetExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Else
        Err.Raise Err.Number, GetErrorSource(PROC_NAME), Err.Description & vbNewLine & "Unable to get instance of Excel.", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
End Function
```

I keep this code in an `XLHelper` class and use it like this.

```
Dim helper As New XLHelper
Dim xl As Excel.Application
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

Set xl = helper.GetExcelApp
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add
Set ws = wb.Worksheets.Add
```

To get the reference of the new sheet/workbook, you just set it equal to the results of the collection's `Add` method.

This works because [`Workbook.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff840478.aspx) and `Worksheets.Add` return the object they create.

Comment: why do you need `XLHelper`?

Comment: You don't *need* it @user3032689. It could easily be a regular module or inline `GetExcelApp`'s logic. I just prefer classes and functions because I think it results in cleaner code.